# Is there a code that makes it jump to another code?

Tags: java

```
if(num == 1){
  // go to num1 == 1
}

if(num1 == 1){
  // to here
}
```

This is just an Example Code not a working code.
The logic of my question is in the Code.

Comment: method calls in Java is the way.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ??Currently unable to understand what you are asking here.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read this on how to ask a question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.

Comment: goto is used for labels in loop. I am not sure whats your question though.

Comment: @Malwaregeek: **No**. `goto` in java is a reserved keyword with no meaning... Loop labels are the label itself followed by `:`.

Comment: Code that just "jumps around" like you suggest is (I cannot stress this enough using text and remaining polite) a bad idea. Structured, well organized (read: follow the "use a method" suggestion) code is your friend. This is why the `goto` keyword in Java is sabotaged.

Comment: Jumping is a bad idea.

Comment: @mah Ever tried an assembler language? :D

Comment: @Kevin yes, quite a bit, and you can write well organized code in assembly language too.

Comment: Agreed with blackpanther, mah and others who suggest to use a method, you don't need a jump here, there should be a much better way to organize your code

Answer (score 2):

Methods can do the trick for you. It looks like this:

```
public void RunThis(int num)
{
     if (num == 1)
         NumIsOne();
     else
         //...
}

public void NumIsOne()    
{
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not recommended - but yes there is a sort of `goto`, for instance:

```
if(num == 1){
    here:
    for (int n = 0; n < 1; n++) {
        break here;
    }
}
```

*p.s.*: in fact the part below doesn't work (jumping downwards or leaving the `if` block is not possible):

```
    if(num1 == 1){
        here:
    }
```

*p.s.* [this site](http://www.steike.com/code/useless/java-goto/) is showing a `Goto` implementation for Java. Lovely ;)

Answer (score 0):

Example of method

```
public class Testing{

public static void main(String[] args){

    int num1 = 0;
    if(num1 == 0){
        runMethod();
    }
}

public static void runMethod(){
    System.out.println("This will run");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
    int num=1;
    int num1=0;
    if(num == 1){
        num1=1;
    }

    if(num1 == 1){
        System.out.println("so?");
    }
```